# Link woommerce product with blog posts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to display in my woocommerce product page some link (perhaps a button?) to some article (ie: blog post).

The idea is: when you enter in the product X you can see all posts related to product X.

Any ideas how to do something like that?

---

Hi,

First of all, sorry but I don't have a code atempt yet. My intention was ask for a direction, because I'm new at wordpress/woocomerce.

I have a woocommerce product page that was builded/customized with Elementor Pro (that is: no code was done yet).

Now I want to put two buttons in this page in order redirect to a post/page (ps: the link content should be dynamic since each product has one post).

So I imagine that somehow I have to "link" the product with the post, but don't know how this kind of thing is done usually.

Perhaps during the creation of the product I could inform a link for the post, and then I could retrieve this information
and display in the button dynamicly.

Maybe now is more clear what direction I need, if not I can provide more information..

thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of07R.jpg)

Comment: Please add more details to your question. [Read how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Add all relevant code and a small working example, so it is easy to understand.

Comment: Also, we expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Hi, I added more details now..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to create a relation between products and posts. This can be achieved in many ways but if you are already using Elementor Pro I recommend you to take a look at the Advanced Custom Fields relationship or post object fields:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

ACF integrates well with Elementor Pro dynamic content. The relationship field also allows to perform reverse queries which can come in handy depending on what you're trying to do.

However, as I mentioned before, it can be achieved in many ways, this is just a simple approach without coding.